# Wordpress Livesite to localhost

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Livesite to localhost?? Can anyone point me in the right direction? I want to take a wordpress site to localhost.

Comment: what do you mean ? what is WordPress Livesite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to migrate a WordPress live site to local.

1. Setup local web & database server using your favorite tool , e.g. XAMPP , MAMP , etc
2. Use this [Search & Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to replace all instances of live domain records to local domain ( e.g. replace `http://example.com` to `http://localhost` )
3. Export WordPress database in live site ( you should now have .sql file dump )
4. Run the Search & Replace Tool again, reverting the changes made in Step 2 ( reverse the Replace )
5. Download all WordPress source in live site to your local web server web root
6. Using your favorite database tool ( e.g. phpMyAdmin ) in local, create a schema and import back the database dump you created in Step 3.
7. Browse your cloned site in local. Enjoy.

This method has been used in deployment of WordPress sites for many times & cases. Definitely working!